# Binding a property to change the listbox items foreground individually for each item

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, mvvm, listbox

I'm trying to change the foreground color of the items in the ListBox individually for each item, I've already posted a similar question but this one is more concrete.

I hoped that the state of the color is reserved for each item added to the ListBox, so I tried to create a property (in this case "HotkeysForeground"), bind it and change the color when the items are added in the "HotkeyManager_NewHotkey" event, the problem it's changing the foreground color for all the items in the ListBox.

How can I do that per item ?

Here is the ViewModel I use.

```
namespace Monkey.Core.ViewModel
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
    using System.Windows.Media;

    using Monkey.Core.SystemMonitor.Accessibility;
    using Monkey.Core.SystemMonitor.Input;

    public class MainWindowViewModel : WorkspaceViewModel
    {
        private readonly FocusManager _focusManager;

        private readonly HotkeyManager _hotkeyManager;

        private readonly ObservableCollection<string> _hotkeys;

        private Color _foregroundColor;

        private string _title;

        public MainWindowViewModel()
        {
            _hotkeys = new ObservableCollection<string>();

            _hotkeyManager = new HotkeyManager();
            _hotkeyManager.NewHotkey += HotkeyManager_NewHotkey;

            _focusManager = new FocusManager();
            _focusManager.Focus += FocusManager_Focus;
        }

        public Color HotkeysForeground
        {
            get
            {
                return _foregroundColor;
            }
            set
            {
                _foregroundColor = value;

                OnPropertyChanged(() => HotkeysForeground);
            }
        }

        public ReadOnlyObservableCollection<string> Hotkeys
        {
            get
            {
                return new ReadOnlyObservableCollection<string>(_hotkeys);
            }
        }

        public string Title
        {
            get
            {
                return _title;
            }
            set
            {
                _title = value;

                OnPropertyChanged(() => Title);
            }
        }

        protected override void OnDispose()
        {
            base.OnDispose();

            _hotkeyManager.Dispose();

            _focusManager.Dispose();
        }

        private void FocusManager_Focus(object sender, FocusManagerEventArgs e)
        {
            Title = e.Title;
        }

        private void HotkeyManager_NewHotkey(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            HotkeysForeground = _hotkeys.Count <= 2 ? Colors.Blue : Colors.Brown;

            _hotkeys.Clear();

            foreach (var hotkey in _hotkeyManager.GetHotkeys())
            {
                _hotkeys.Add(hotkey);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the view.

```
<Window x:Class="Monkey.View.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        Title="{Binding Mode=OneWay, Path=Title, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Height="200" Width="200" ShowInTaskbar="False" WindowStyle="ToolWindow" Topmost="True" ResizeMode="CanResizeWithGrip" AllowsTransparency="False">
    <Window.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding HotkeysForeground}" x:Key="HotkeysBrush"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <ListBox 
        Canvas.Left="110" 
        Canvas.Top="74" 
        Name="HotkeyList" 
        Height="Auto" Width="Auto" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" 
        BorderThickness="0"
        ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False"
        ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
        ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Hotkeys}" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" FontSize="20">
        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
            </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Label Content="{Binding}" Foreground="{StaticResource HotkeysBrush}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Window>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try making your Foreground binding a "OneTime" binding.

Comment: Nop, doing that results a constant blue items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like bad design to me. If you have more data than a hotkey string just create a class and store the color together with the display string as separate properties.

**Edit:** Example:

```cs
public class HotkeyViewModel
{
    private readonly string _DisplayString;
    public string DisplayString { get { return _DisplayString; } }

    private readonly Color _Color;
    public Color Color { get { return _Color; } }

    public HotkeyViewModel(string displayString, Color color)
    {
        _DisplayString = displayString;
        _Color = color;
    }
}
```

You can also make the properties editable, but if any bindings should update you need to [implement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229614.aspx) [`INPC`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx).

The new collection should then be of type `ObservableCollection<HotkeyViewModel>` and the template has two bindings:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <Label Content="{Binding DisplayString}">
        <Label.Background>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Color}" />
        </Label.Background>
    </Label>
</DataTemplate>
```

(You could also make the property a `Brush` and bind directly to `Background`)

Comment: In other words you're telling me to use ListBoxItem rather than a string ? :p

Comment: @Eyal-Shilony: Actually that is a **bad** idea. I meant that you create **a new class** which has two properties, don't move i'll edit my answer.

Comment: @Eyal-Shilony: Added example.

Comment: @Eyal-Shilony: Yes, you should not have any UI-elements or UI-related classes in the model or even viewmodel. If you have more than one property a new ViewModel *is* justified.

Comment: @Eyal-Shilony: Well, it's not quite a proper ViewModel, the model is somewhat missing, if you have one you can plug that in of course.